# How do I check if a screen has an associated speaker

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, device-driver

I'm developing a MacOS application in Swift. I wanted to know if a screen (NSScreen) has an associated speaker and if that speaker has volume settings which can be adjusted.

Some monitor units have speakers attached to them. The monitor (screen + speaker) connect to laptop via a single cable.

**I want to find out which monitors have volume settings that can be adjusted and how to adjust those settings**.

I know libraries like [ddcctl](https://github.com/kfix/ddcctl) can set volume for these speakers connected to monitors, I haven't found out how.

Ddcctl can correctly locate connected screens and adjust settings on them. I have used it to update screen brightness/contrast so that works (my screen doesn't have a speaker).

I would like to know the solution even if it isn't strictly swift/xcode.

Comment: There are a *lot* of layers to this question. Perhaps you could update your question with more detail into what information you *have* gathered and what you're still missing. (e.g. Have you scanned the display's EDID for audio capabilities? Have you tried sending DDC commands? Did they work? If not, does it work to adjust volume on the same display in other OSes which might have vendor drivers? Are you trying to tie in with macOS's audio system, i.e. match to a Core Audio HAL device?)

Comment: I've updated with what I have tried. I wasn't aware of what EDID was before this.

Comment: The EDID will tell you if a display has any audio capabilities at all (in the CEA extension block). I don't think there's anything there about volume controls though. I don′t know much about the non-EDID aspects of DDC but perhaps you can find your answer in the source code for this project: https://github.com/the0neyouseek/MonitorControl (I've done a lot of work in the area of macOS audio devices & displays, but it sounds like you don't have a specific issue there.)

Comment: (Note that even if a display has audio capability and a volume control in the OSD, the MonitorControl app may fail to actually set anything, as is the case on my display from Acer, so I'm guessing it doesn't implement a reliable availability check for that feature.)